# How do I read each line of a file as a variable in php

Tags: php

How do I take each line from a file and turn it into a variable in php?
I've tried to test for `if($var2==$var1)`, and if it does, to output a `True` statment. To make it easier to understand what `$var1` equals, I've wrote `echo"$var1"` to make sure its being read correctly; and it IS outputting the correct value of `$var1`; However its still not giving a `True` output, and if I attach an `else{}` statement, all variables output as `False`. Here is what ive tried:

```
<?php
    $remove = $_POST["remove"];
    echo "$remove";
    $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('allowedUsers.dat'));
    foreach($lines as $line){
        if($line == $remove){
            echo"True";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't rely on `echo` to debug your program. Use `var_dump`, which is able to show you much more information and will most likely reveal the cause of the mismatch.

Comment: Side note: your title doesn't match the question content. You're actually asking about variable comparison, you're already loading every line into a variable (`$line`).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try trim for the comparison, as it could be you have extra spaces or "\r" included.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Furthermore, you should probably use === depending on what the content is that is coming in from "remove":
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
<?php
    $remove = $_POST["remove"];
    echo "$remove";
    $lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('allowedUsers.dat'));
    foreach($lines as $line){
        if(trim($line) === $remove){
            echo"True";
        }
    }
?>
```